# Django - Is it possible to transfer template tags to client asynchronously?

Tags: ajax, django, post, get

I am looking for a way to receive template tags, 
specifically a paypal form generated in views.
I've been trying with jquery $.post and $.get to no avail. 
Also considered ajax but it seems to receive only json
one of my template tags is a form, and it can't be converted to json:
TypeError: Object of type PayPalPaymentsForm is not JSON serializable

I need this for users that click the browser go back button when in paypal,
in case that happens I need to send the price to the view
and generate the form, 
if I don't send the items and discount I will get multivaluedictkey

**views.py**

```
return render(request, 'pagamentos/payment.html', { 'morada':morada, 'telemovel':telemovel,'codigo_postal':codigo_postal, 'cidade':cidade, 'form': form })
```

**payment.html**

```
$.post( "/token/", {
    items: x.toString(),
    desconto: y.toString() ,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
    function( data ) {
      console.log(data.morada)
      console.log(data.telemovel)
      console.log(data.cidade)
      console.log(data.codigo_postal)
      console.log(data.form)
});
```

it doesn't work like that.

Looking for a solution to load the template tags in the javascript ready function, without additional buttons.

Comment: `data` will arrive as HTML. You won't be able to access `data.morada` etc. If that's what you want, consider sending this data as JSON from your view instead of rendering to a template.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to convert a form into json in server? and to html in client?

Comment: Is that JS code you posted in your question in the `payment.html` template?

Comment: yes this is in payment.html

Comment: I need this for users that click the browser go back button when in paypal, in case that happens I need to send the items and discount to the view and generate the form, if I don't send the price I will get multivaluedictkey

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to keep the django variables in a JS variable during rendering.

Something like this should work:

*payment.html*

```
var data = {
    morada: '{{ morada }}',
    telemovel: '{{ telemovel }}',
    cidade: '{{ cidade }}',
    // ... other variables
};


$.post(...);
```

Comment: I am doing this. It works correctly. However What I am addressing is returning from paypal to payments.html. I need to post two values when I go to payment.html( items and desconto ) otherwise I get multivaluedictkey. so I was trying $.post(), but then I don't see how to receive the variables (morada, telemovel, form...)

Comment: @Jaime38130 The thing is templates are rendered on the server, before they reach the client. Only way to receive raw data like this is through JSON. You can use `request.is_ajax()` in your to return JSON data for ajax requests and to render HTML template otherwise.

Comment: I understand. I printed type(form) and I get this: <class 'paypal.standard.forms.PayPalPaymentsForm'>, so this is what I send in my template tag at the moment. I'm wondering if sending the form to payment.html trough json will work, what you think?

Comment: TypeError: Object of type PayPalPaymentsForm is not JSON serializable

Comment: @Jaime38130 Python classes aren't JSON serializable. Even if they were, the browser doesn't understand Python, so that won't work anyway. You have two options: (1) send the form specific data as JSON and dynamically generate form on the browser using javascript. (2) Or render the form on the server and update the template using javascript. This is easier, but you won't be able to access individual variables because everything will come as pre rendered HTML.